# Error: The process cannot access the file '…' because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, filestream

I am downloading file and sending back the changed file to end user throw httphandler in sharepoint 2010, but some times i am getting the error "The process cannot access the file '…' because it is being used by another process" Here is my code:

```
string myFile="MypdfFile.pdf";
string downloadFilePath = @"C:\Windows\Temp";
if (!Directory.Exists(downloadFilePath))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(downloadFilePath);
}

string downloadFilePathAndName = downloadFilePath + "\\" + myFile.Name;
newFile = downloadFilePathAndName;
content = myFile.OpenBinary();                                                     

using (PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(content))
{                                                                                                  
    var fileStream = new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write,FileShare.ReadWrite);
    var document = new Document(pdfReader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1));
    var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fileStream);
    document.Open();                                                        

    for (var i = 1; i <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; i++)
    {
        document.NewPage();
        var baseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA_BOLD, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
        var importedPage = writer.GetImportedPage(pdfReader, i);
        var contentByte = writer.DirectContent;
        contentByte.BeginText();
        contentByte.SetFontAndSize(baseFont, 12);
        string mytext = " ";                                                          

        contentByte.ShowTextAligned(2, mytext, 100, 200, 0);
        contentByte.EndText();
        contentByte.AddTemplate(importedPage, 0, 0);
    }

    document.Close();
    writer.Close();
    fileStream.Dispose();
    fileStream.Close();
    pdfReader.Dispose();
    pdfReader.Close();  

}
```

I had kept the FileStream inside the `using` statement but that is also not solving the issue.

Comment: I'm unsure wether it's the cause but you're closing and disposing the objects in wrong order. First, you need to close the file access and then dispose the objects.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping the `FileStream` inside another `using` isn't enough by itself - you also need to wrap *it* in a `using()` statement as well.  You also don't need to `Dispose()` the thing you're `using`.

Try this (untested):

```
using (var pdfReader = new PdfReader(content))
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write,FileShare.ReadWrite))
using (var document = new Document(pdfReader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1)))
using (var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fileStream))
{
  document.Open();                                                        
  for (var i = 1; i <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; i++)
  {
    document.NewPage();
    var baseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA_BOLD, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
    var importedPage = writer.GetImportedPage(pdfReader, i);
    var contentByte = writer.DirectContent;
    contentByte.BeginText();
    contentByte.SetFontAndSize(baseFont, 12);
    string mytext = " ";                                                          

    contentByte.ShowTextAligned(2, mytext, 100, 200, 0);
    contentByte.EndText();
    contentByte.AddTemplate(importedPage, 0, 0);
  }
  // These lines may be unnecessary.
  writer.Close();
  document.Close();
  fileStream.Close();
  pdfReader.Close();
}
```